# Set Default MODI (Microsoft Office Document Image) Writer File Format

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-office

I need to enforce the MDI file format as the default choice for MODI printing rather than TIFF.  Anyone know if this is a registry setting or something that's available in Group Policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following on MSDN:

---

Under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\MODI\MDI Writer\

**PrivateFlags**

This will be 0 for MDI Format and 16 (decimal) for TIFF format

**TIFDPI**

Controls the DPI for the TIFF format, allowed values are (in decimal) 100, 200 and 300

**COMPIMGEMF**

1 for compressing images in the document, 0 for not

**DefaultFolder**

Default output folder

**OpenInMODI**

Controls whether or not show the image in “Microsoft office document imaging” after the printout is done. If the value is 1 the “Microsoft office document imaging” will show up, if it’s 0 it will not.

**Public_Orientation**

Control the page orientation, 1 for Portrait, 2 for Landscape.

**Public_PaperSize**

Controls the page size

Answer (score 0):

Open MODI (you can find it All Program Files - MS OFFICE - MS OFFICE TOOLS)
Goto Menu item Tools-Options
Open the tab OTHER
Click the button File Import Preferences